# Android. Using fragments in RecyclerView is it right or wrong?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a card which addition to other information can contain an image, image slider (third-party library), or video (YouTubeAPI). Earlier I used to card layout, all three media elements (image, slider, video) and, depending on the needs, modify their visibility, hiding unnecessary elements, leaving visible only the necessary.

Then I decided to try to use the fragments. Did the three fragments, for each item (note that the fragments of a class contain all the logic element, he should just pass parameters to initialize, and the rest he will do himself), and tried to use it in RecyclerView. Earlier in my card had three elements, but now I just wanted to put me right fragment in a special container in the card.

I also read that the use of fragments in RecyclerView is a bad practice. Question - is worth in this case the use of fragments, for the sake of simplicity (these fragments are also used in other Activiti and now all logic of the media elements moved to their classes of fragments).
Or I must use an old scheme - the card directly contains all the media items that I dynamically made visible/invisible and filled as needed?

[image]

Comment: Using a fragment as a container for the different components in this case is unnecessary and complicates your structure. Look into DataBinding and using MVVM. You can seamlessly handle visibility of items and it integrates with RecyclerView beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely clear what your requirement is to modify the views. Each fragment within RecyclerView is a ViewHolder.

This may be worth reading:

[Heterogenous Layouts inside RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Heterogeneous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)

- RecyclerView is capable of being aware of more than one type of ViewHolder

Comment: My card view (recycler view item) can contains only one media item (image, image slider or video). Since I use recycler view - I need create and reuse created card view. I'm looking the best way to do it.

Comment: Note: I do not want to create a separate card view type for each media. Card view contains other views that are not changed. Media element just a part of my card view and they may change dynamically (image, image slider or video).

Comment: Use the method above which allows recycler view to be aware of three types of ViewHolders. Create three layouts for each ViewHolder. Now create a fourth layout which has those shared view elements and use the <include/> tag in xml. [Re-using Layouts with <include/>](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)